# How to make a smoother slide_up/down animation on a Text View?

Tags: android, animation, textview, fadein, fadeout

I have 3 Text Views representing the information belonging to 3 categories. I also have 3 other Text Views that represent the title of each category.

These Text Views are constrained against each other (Text View A Title is constrained above Text View A Information, which is constrained Text View B Title, which is constrained above Text View B Information). Looks like this:

[image]

I have written code so that when a Text View title is clicked, the corresponding Text View information slides down and shows information.

My issue here is that when, for example, Text View B information populates with data, Text View C Title appears where the end of Text View B information will shortly be, but in a sudden and Jerky movement (the order of Text Views is still correct, it is the jerky movement I don't want). After 2 seconds (the time of the slide_down) Text View B information is filled and is plush above Text View C title:

[image]

Similarily, when the title is clicked again the scroll_up is triggered but Text View C Title appears directly under Text View B Information in a teleport. Then the sliding occurs and the text goes through Text View C Title:

[image]

Is there any way so that the Text View below the Text Viewing that is sliding, will be pushed in the sliding motion of the slide up or slide_down, rather than this teleportation that is occurring?

I've been fiddling with the code for a while now and I am stuck.

The method that calls the animation:

```
public void ShowWeekly(View view) {

    if(WeeklyTextView.isShown()){
        slide_up(this, WeeklyTextView);
        WeeklyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        WeeklyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        slide_down(this, WeeklyTextView);
    }
}
```

The slide_up xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

android:fillAfter="false">
<scale
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/test"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

Slide_down xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Text Views are in a constraint layout within a Scroll View. Here are the text views:

```
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OverallButton">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/OverallButton"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/OverallTextView"
            android:text="Overall Statistics\n"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick="ShowDistance"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/OverallTextViewContent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OverallTextView"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weekly Statistics\n"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/WeeklyTextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OverallTextViewContent"
            android:onClick="ShowWeekly"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/WeeklyTextViewContent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/WeeklyTextView"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Best Statistics\n"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/BestTextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/WeeklyTextViewContent"
            android:onClick="ShowBest"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/BestTextViewContent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BestTextView"
            />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to give it a quick fix by using a runnable thread that waits for a period of time (the time you set the animation length) before the Text View C title moves back. This gives the Text View B content time to fully shrink, before Text View C title snaps back to it's original position before the list scrolled down.

Text View C title still has the snap jerky motion when returning, but it actually looks good

Here is the new method:

```
if(OverallTextViewContent.isShown()){

        slide_up(this, OverallTextViewContent);

        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OverallTextViewContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```